# Hibernate collection caching problems

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

I have the following 2 Hibernate entites:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICLE_BRAND")
public class VehicleBrand implements java.io.Serializable {

  ...

  @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 1000)
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "vehiclebrand")
  public Set<VehicleModel> getVehicleModels() {
    return vehicleModels;
  }

  ...

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICLE_MODEL")
public class VehicleModel implements java.io.Serializable {

  ...

  @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 1000)
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="VECHILE_BRAND_ID")
  public VehicleBrand getVehicleBrand() {
    return this.vehicleBrand;
  }

  ...

}
```

And I have the following unit test which tests VehicleBrand and VehicleModel:

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition txDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
txDef.setName("test1");
txDef.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);
TransactionStatus txStatus = txManager.getTransaction(txDef);

// Load brand "1" object.
VehicleBrand brand = (VehicleBrand) factory.getVehicleBrandDAO().findFirstByName("1");
assertNotNull(brand);

// Check if model "X" exists for brand "1" through collection.
Set<VehicleModel> models = brand.getVehicleModels();
for (final VehicleModel model : models) {
  assertFalse(model.getName().equals("X"));
}

// Add model "X" to brand "1".
VehicleModel model = new VehicleModel();
model.setName("X");
model.setValidFrom(new Date());
model.setVehicleBrand(brand);
factory.getVehicleModelDAO().create(model);

txManager.commit(txStatus);

txDef = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
txDef.setName("test2");
txDef.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRED);
txStatus = txManager.getTransaction(txDef);

// Check that model is added to database.
model = (VehicleModel) factory.getVehicleModelDAO().findFirstByName("X");
assertNotNull(model);
assertEquals(model.getVehicleBrandId().longValue(), 1L);

// Check if model X exists for brand "1" through collection.
brand = (VehicleBrand) factory.getVehicleBrandDAO().findFirstByName("1");
models = brand.getVehicleModels();
boolean found = false;
for (final VehicleModel model2 : models) {
  if (model2.getName().equals("X")) {
    found = true;
  }
}
assertTrue(found);

txManager.commit(txStatus);
```

Can someone explain me why the last line fails?

Comment: Can you update the code with the snippets for `getNavn` or the associated member that would be stored in the database ?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, it is called getName and I have added getter/annotation definitions to the entity in the question

Comment: I have updated the test case to ensure that new transaction is started between requests

Comment: This is turning into a wild goose chase now :p Did you implement the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods for the `VehicleModel` model class? That would be useful as well.

Comment: yes, equals and hashcode are implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly fails because you're executing all this in the same transaction, and thus the same VehicleBrand instance is always returned from the session cache.

Since you forgot to maintain both sides of the association when you created your VehicleModel (i.e. you assigned the brand to the new model, but forgot to add the created model to the brand's collection of models), the same set of models is always returned, and doesn't contain the newly created model.

Comment: 1) Find requests are executed in different hibernate sessions, 2) Also I can see from the logs that on each findFirstByName there is an SQL query executed against the database

Comment: Have you checked that the model is indeed written in database at the end of your first transaction, and that its name and brand ID are correct (since the transaction is committed, you should be able to see it in the database)?